# What REGEX pattern will get me the last portion of a string?

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to merge HUNDREDS of .rtf files using Powershell.

Here's the format:
bunch of CSS stuff followed by the part I want.....

```
 {\rtf1\ansi {\fonttbl{\f0 Arial;}}{\colortbl\red255\green255\blue255;}{\stylesheet
}\paperw11685\paperh1560\margl600\margr600\margt600\margb600\pard\plain\f0\fs28\cf0
\ql\li75\ri75\fi0\b Instructions: }
```

In this case, I wish to retain "Instructions:"

```
{\rtf1\ansi {\fonttbl{\f0 Arial;}}{\colortbl\red255\green255\blue255;}{\stylesheet
}\paperw10530\paperh1920\margl600\margr600\margt600\margb600\pard\plain\f0\fs28\cf0
\ql\li75\ri75\fi0\b You will be presented with fifty (50) questions which are ran
domly selected from a pool of hundreds of questions. }
```

In this case I wish to retain "You will be presented with fifty (50) questions which are ran
    domly selected from a pool of hundreds of questions."

The Powershell script is this:

```
$files = (dir *.rtf)
$outfile = "AllQuestions.rtf"
$files | %{
$_.Name | Add-Content  $outfile 
$MyVar = Get-Content $_.Name    
$MyVar=$MyVar -replace ".*b\s","" | Add-Content  $outfile 
}
```

My intent was to replace all the string UP TO "\b " with nothin ( "" ).
I used /.*b\s/ (fwd slants as delimiters, .*="everything zero or more times", b\s=the letter b and a space)I'm  partially successful;its stripping a portion

```
{\rtf1........cf0
\ql\li75\ri75\fi0\b Instructions: }
```

to

```
{\rtf1........cf0 
Instructions: }
```

This makes me think there's a linefeed after cf0 .  I tried to stripp out all the linefeeds

```
-replace "\n*",""
```

that didn't change the string.

But I wanna dump ALL the previous string (from the {\rtf1.... to right before the final text) & be left with that end text.....at this point I'll take the trailing "}" dump it in a subsequent -replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use look behind regex
Added capturing group (.*)
and non-capturing group (?: }) so that it matches exactly till }

```
(?<=\\b )(.*)(?: })$
```

Comment: I know the OP said that they would accept the trailing ` }` but they did state that they didn't really want it. You may want to set a capturing group and then a non-capturing group for the trailing ` }` there. `(?<=\\b )(.*)(?: })$`

Comment: Yay. worked. Thanks.Can you explain the ?<= part of that???  I think \\b is escaping the backslash, the letter b and a space.  ....and at the end, you're anchoring with a $ to start the search backwards from the end???

Comment: @jazaddict, ?<= is used to tell that it is look behind approach. so wherever \b  is found it will find that and then we will get any characters after that look behind match. the tutorial at http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html has good examples

Comment: @jazaddict, also http://regex101.com/#python will explain the approach in detail when you copy the regex

Comment: @Rajesh THe comments instructions say not to thank you, so I won't.  But understand that I'm very appreciative of the kind explanation and link to other explanations.   ;) ....and I'm not thanking TheMadTech either for dumping my trailing "}" ;)

Comment: @Rajesh: THe term "behind" has always been a problem for me until your explanation using the phrase "...and then we will get any chars AFTER...."  The word "behind" apparently means "After" to my way of thinking...essentially starting the search "after" the "look behind match".  Kudos.  (thats not like thanks, so ....)

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex ($ refers to the end of a line) to get the "Instructions:" or "You will be presented with fifty (50) questions which are ran domly selected from a pool of hundreds of questions."" portion:

```
\\b(.*)}$
```

Comment: This will match everything past the first `\b` found. In the example it will match `lue255;}{\stylesheet
}\paperw10530\paperh1920\margl600\margr600\margt600\margb600\pard\plain\f0\fs28\cf0
\ql\li75\ri75\fi0\b You will be presented with fifty (50) questions which are ran
domly selected from a pool of hundreds of questions. `

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
.*?\\b(?!.*?\\b)[ ]*([^}]+)
```

To:

```
$1
```

Example

```
$MyVar -replace $regex,'$1'
```

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/VdSfQJ1vxT)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a multiline regex:

```
$text = (@'
{\rtf1\ansi {\fonttbl{\f0 Arial;}}{\colortbl\red255\green255\blue255;}{\stylesheet
}\paperw10530\paperh1920\margl600\margr600\margt600\margb600\pard\plain\f0\fs28\cf0
\ql\li75\ri75\fi0\b You will be presented with fifty (50) questions which are randomly selected from a pool of hundreds of questions. }
'@)

$text -replace '(?ms).+\\b([^}]+)}.*','$1'

 You will be presented with fifty (50) questions which are randomly selected from a pool of hundreds of questions.
```

Use the -Raw switch with Get-Content to read the file as multi-line text:

```
$files = (dir *.rtf)
$outfile = "AllQuestions.rtf"
$files | %{
$_.Name | Add-Content  $outfile 
$MyVar = Get-Content $_.Name -Raw    
$MyVar=$MyVar -replace '(?ms).+\\b([^}]+)}.*','$1' | Add-Content  $outfile 
}
```